# Repeat placement of a Label on a form

Tags: vb.net, label, controls

From what I have seen, if I try to place a label on a form more than once, only the last one is allowed (along with some weird other happenings).  I have a form which will have many Textboxes with degree and radian values.  Is it possible to somehow use the same Label (or any other control for that matter) more than once so that I do not have to make multiple instances of Π and ° labels to place next to the values in the Textboxes?  I realize that this is relatively minor in this instance, but it could have applications later.

Comment: The quick answer to this is that you can have multiple controls on the page, but you must have unique ID's for each control.

Comment: That's what I'm afraid of.  Here I go repeating.  But, thank you for your help.

Comment: one lable would not be able to have more than one location (so as to be next to different text controls).  But you can make copies so you dont have to re-enter the properties or clone one so the events are shared

Comment: You can also dynamically load them in a loop rather than placing them all by hand in the form designer.

Comment: Steven, I am doing it dynamically, but you seem to have another idea than how I'm doing it.  In Java, I could just use new JLabel("Π") and that would create a temporary object to display, but VB.Net didn't seem to like that.

Comment: Sounds like you have TextBoxes and/or Labels that constitute a "unit".  Consider developing a **UserControl** for them.  Also, have you considered using a DataGridView?

Comment: Winforms or ASP.NET?

Comment: Idle, I'll look into those suggestions.  I'm new to the terminology, but I'm assuming that a UserControl is a group of controls, like on a panel, which is pretty much what I'm doing at the moment.

Comment: Fabio, at the moment it is for VB, but my job will involve a lot of VBScript also.